# PHP OOP CURL proxy error

Tags: php, curl, proxy

```
<?php
class Isis_Expl
{
    const USERAGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13';

    public static $ch;

    public static $proxyType;
    public static $proxy;
    public static $postFields;
    public static $cookie;

    public static function setProxy($proxy, $proxyType = '1')
    {
        self::$proxy = $proxy;
        switch ($proxyType)
        {
            case '4':
                self::$proxyType = 'CURLPROXY_SOCKS4';
                break;
            case '5':
                self::$proxyType = 'CURLPROXY_SOCKS5';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public static function init($url)
    {
        self::$ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt(self::$ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt(self::$ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);        
        curl_setopt(self::$ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt(self::$ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, self::USERAGENT);
        curl_setopt(self::$ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt(self::$ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt(self::$ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
        curl_setopt(self::$ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt(self::$ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        self::_getProxy();
        self::_getPost();
        self::_getCookie();

        $content = curl_exec(self::$ch); 

        if (curl_errno(self::$ch))
        {
            echo curl_error(self::$ch);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return $content;
        }
    }

    protected function _getProxy()
    {
        if (self::$proxyType) curl_setopt(self::$ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, self::$proxyType);        
        if (self::$proxy) curl_setopt(self::$ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, self::$proxy);
    }

    protected function _getPost()
    {
        if (self::$postFields)
        {
            curl_setopt(self::$ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt(self::$ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, self::$postFields);
        }
    }

    protected function _getCookie()
    {
        if (self::$cookie) curl_setopt(self::$ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, self::$cookie);
    }   
}

Isis_Expl::setProxy('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX');
echo Isis_Expl::init('http://google.com');
```

Output: **Recv failure: Connection was reset**

But if I commented "//Isis_Expl::setProxy('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX');" that output is ok..
Where is a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, don't use a static class when an instance would be more appropriate.  You have state here, so use an instance.  Secondly, you may want to name your methods better.  `_getProxy()` I would think would return something, not effect the state of the app.

Now, for your exact question:

1. Is it a HTTP proxy?  If so, should you be setting `CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL` to true?
2. You're declaring `proxyType` to be 1 by default in `setProxy`, but then you never set `self::$proxyType`.  And you never set `CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE` to `CURLPROXY_HTTP` (you shouldn't need to, but I'd be explicit).
3. You never declare any authentication for the proxy.  Is it an open proxy?
4. Are you sure the proxy is actually listening on that IP and Port?  That's a non-standard port...  Try opening a connection from the server and see what happens:

   ```
   $f  = fsockopen('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 'XXXX');
   if (!$f) die('Server not accepting connections');
   fwrite($f, "q\r\n\r\n");
   var_dump(fread($f, 4048));
   fclose($f);
   ```

Comment: @Isis: Ok, I would HIGHLY suggest closing that.  You're now broadcasting the proxy info to everyone on the internet.  Change something and make it use authentication.  But what about the other suggestions?